# Pointing to an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

How do you create a pointer to an array?

```
std::string string_array[5 /*<-an arbitrary length determined by a function*/];
std::string** array_pointer = &string_array;
```

I'll compile this on a Windows 7, 64-bit using MinGW version 4.8.1, and get this error:

`main.cpp:116:28: error: cannot convert 'std::string (*)[(((sizetype)<anonymous>) + 1)] {aka std::basic_string<char> (*)[(((sizetype)<anonymous>) + 1)]}' to std::string** {aka std::basic_string<char>**}' in initialization
  string** array_pointer = &string_array;`

From what I can infer from this wall of text, it doesn't seem to want to set `array_pointer` equal to the address of `string_array`.  Yet as I understand from [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) this should compile, because an array is essentially a pointer, so I should create a pointer pointer and point it to the address of my other pointer(my array), correct?

Comment: Use a vector of strings to avoid this rubbish. `std::vector<std::string> *` easy peasy

Comment: "because an array is essentially a pointer" unfortunately, not true.

Comment: Thanks to @NeilKirk, that solution worked much better than what I was trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need one `*`, i.e.,

```
 std::string* array_pointer = string_array;
```

Arrays decay to pointers so you don't need the ampersand at all. Their relationship with pointers can be sometimes confusing, but in a lot of places (like here) their are just interchangeable.

You can also do something that is actually a pointer to an array, but I don't think it is what you want in this case. The syntax would be

```
 std::string (*array_pointer)[5] = &string_array;
```

And here you need to know the length. The actual machine language code generated would be the same, but the compiler will do some more restrictive type-checking for you. I.e., if you replace the 5 with 4 above, you'll get a compile error.

Comment: Thanks to @toth and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c?rq=1) for clearing up how arrays work, this helped a lot.

Comment: @chris, yes, that's what I meant, thanks, edited to fix.